# Increment <ValueName> when using reg add from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I have a group of PCs that I need to add registry keys to.

I currently use a batch file with the following line to add a registry key in windows:

`reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\Test" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d Test /f`

Note the `/v 1`

Later, I need to add a new value under this key. Some machines will already have the first value so I want to add the new one with `/v 2` but if the machine does not have any values yet, I want the new one added as `/v 1`

What I'd like to do is get the last value under this key, get the `ValueName` param as an int, increment it, and use the result as the `ValueName` for the key that Im adding. If there is no value yet, `ValueName` should default to `1`

How can I do this in a batch file?

Comment: Do a `reg query` first looking for `/v 1` if fails then add the `/v 1` if it succeeds then add the `/v 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\Test"
reg query "%key%" >Nul 2>&1
If "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" ( goto NoExist ) else ( goto Exist )

:Exist
Color 0A
echo "%key%" Exist 
reg add "%key%" /v 2 /t REG_SZ /d Test /f
pause
exit /b

:NoExist
Color 0C
echo "%key%" dosen't Exist
pause
goto CreateKey

:CreateKey
cls
Color 0B
reg add "%key%" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d Test /f>nul 2>&1
If "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" ( echo The Key is added succesfuly into the registry !
    ) else ( 
    color 0C & echo There was an error !
 )
pause
Exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, in the wild, these Keys may have any number of items already there so I really need to increment the highest found value. I was able to work it out though :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Differences in syntax between executing commands in CMD vs in a .bat file made this VERY difficult to work out, but this is what finally worked:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
SET /a ValueName=0
SET Query=REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\Test
SET Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\Test
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (%Query%) do ( 
 IF %%a GTR !ValueName! (
  SET /a ValueName=%%a+1
 )
)
endlocal
REG ADD %Key% /v %ValueName% /t REG_SZ /d Test2
PAUSE
```